# JS template

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как правильно сделать шаблон.Есть таблица я ее разделяю на 3 части,начало контент и конец,но получается так что када выводится начало таблицы,браузер сам создает конечный тег </table>.

```
<script type="text/template" id="tpl_start">
    <table border="1" id="exercise_tbl"
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Image</th>
        </tr>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="tpl_content">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="exercise" value="%id%"/>
            </td>
            <td>%title%</td>
            <td>%category%</td>
            <td>%description%</td>
            <td>
                <img src="<?php echo base_url().'upload/'; ?>%image%" width="50" height="50"/>
            </td>
        </tr>      
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="tpl_end">
    </table> 
</script>

var btn_add_block = $('#btn_add_block');
    var main_div = $('#wrapper');
    var exercise_tpl_start = $('#tpl_start').html();
    var exercise_tpl_content = $('#tpl_content').html();
    var exercise_tpl_end = $('#tpl_end').html();

    btn_add_block.click(function(){

        var exercise_div = $("<div id='exercise_div'></div>");
        var btn_add_exercise = $("<p id='p_add_ex'><input type='button' value='Add exercise'></p>");

        main_div.append(exercise_div);
        exercise_div.append(btn_add_exercise);

        btn_add_exercise.click(function() { 
            exercise_div.append(exercise_tpl_start);
                $.ajax({
                    url:'load_ex',
                    dataType:'json',
                    success:function(data){ 
                        $.each(data,function(key,value){

                            var new_tpl_content = exercise_tpl_content;

                            alert(new_tpl_content);

                            $.each(value,function(title,exercise){
                                var expr = new RegExp('%' + title + '%', 'g');
                                new_tpl_content = new_tpl_content.replace(expr,exercise);
                            });
                            exercise_div.append(new_tpl_content);

                        }); 
                    }
                });
            exercise_div.append(exercise_tpl_end);
        });
    });
```

Comment: решил проблему с помощью конкатинации всех 3-ех шаблонов

Comment: @Женька Сидоров, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.